# How to prove 2 triangles in a circle are similar when only 1 arc measure is given.

Tags: triangles, circles

I recently encountered this math problem:
[image: Possibly Impossible Problem]

And I got quite stuck. The problem requires proofs, and gives minimal information. I have been able to determine that angle $AEB$ is congruent to angle $DEC$ because of the Vertical Angles Theorem; and that angle $AED$ is congruent to angle $BEC$, also because of the Vertical Angles Theorem. But I'm stuck at this point and have no idea how to get any closer to proving the proof.

Comment: $\widehat{AED} =  \widehat{BEC}$ as at intersections, while $\widehat{DAE} =  \widehat{CBE}$ and $\widehat{ADE} =  \widehat{BCE}$ as angles off a common chord

Comment: Hint: angles DAC and DBC are standing on the same arc.

Comment: The $130^\circ$ is not useful

Comment: @Henry how does AED = BEC? Are you talking about AED and BEC as angles?

Comment: Yes I am talking about angles.  If you prefer, $\angle{AED} =  \angle{BEC}$ while $\angle{DAE} =  \angle{CBE}$ and $\angle{ADE} =  \angle{BCE}$

Comment: How did you get to those statements? (Don't forget that the problem requests a proof table)

Comment: I think you might  try to prove these

Answer (score 0):

Angles $DAC$ and $DBC$ are each one half the intercepted arc $DC$ so each is $65$ degrees. There is also a pair of opposite angles from two intersecting chords.

Note I was typing this while above comments came in. If someone wants can delete answer.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $E$ and $P$ are the same point and that $\frac{130}{2}=85$

Comment: @Henry Typo, meant $65.$ But the measure of *any* angle inscribed in a circle has half the measure of the intercepted arc. That has nothing to do with the center of the angle even being on a side of the angle.

Comment: So you can conclude those two angles $\angle DAC$ and $\angle DBC$ are equal, but not how large they are, because they are half $\angle AEB$ rather than half $\angle APB =130^\circ$

Comment: @Henry I am confused by your last comment. When I refer to the intercepted arc of an angle inscribed in a circle I mean the following. Say the three points $X,Y,Z$ are on a circle $C$ with center $O$ and my angle is formed with its vertex at $Y$ and its two sides $XY$ and $ZY.$ Then by the intercepted arc I mean one takes that part of the circle $C$ which is bounded by $X$ and $Z$ and is "cut off" by the interior of angle $XYZ.$ Call that "arc $XZ$". Then the measure of angle $XYZ$ is half the measure of arc $XZ.$ I am applying this to both angles $DAC$ and $DBC$ each intercepting arc $DC.$

Comment: Re-reading what we both wrote, you may be correct

Comment: @Henry Please let me know whether you end up agreeing with my answer. [Not looking for points, just curious...]

Comment: I agree that the angles at $A$ and $B$ are equal to each other.  A similar argument that the angles at $C$ and $D$ are equal are equal to each other.   So you have two similar triangles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126340/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-henry).